# Django quiz application with different types of questions

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, django-rest-framework

I am building Django quiz application that will contain questions of 3 types of answers:

1. Single option answer;
2. Multiple option answer;
3. Text answer;

I am not sure how should I design django models for such pattern.

At the moment my models look like this:

```
class Question(CoreModel, models.Model):
    TYPES = (
        (1, 'radio'),
        (2, 'checkbox'),
        (3, 'text'),
    )
    type = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=TYPES, default='radio')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=2048, null=False, blank=False)

class Choice(CoreModel, models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=2048, null=False, blank=False)
    correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Answer(CoreModel, models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    choice = models.ForeignKey(Choice, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=2048, null=False, blank=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

But it looks like it will not work as expected.
I really don't like 'choice' and 'text' fields at the same time in my Answer model but that’s all I could think of.

Any ideas or suggestions? Maybe I need some more other models for further logic?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something around the lines of:

```
class Quiz(CoreModel, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=2048, null=False, blank=False)

class Question(CoreModel, models.Model):
    TYPES = (
        (1, 'radio'),
        (2, 'checkbox'),
        (3, 'text'),
    )
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=TYPES, default='radio')
    prompt = models.CharField(max_length=2048, null=False, blank=False)
    correct_free_text = models.CharField(max_length=2048, null=True, blank=True)
    rank = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)

class Choice(CoreModel, models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=2048, null=False, blank=False)
    correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    rank = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)

class Answer(CoreModel, models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    choice = models.ForeignKey(Choice, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    free_text = models.CharField(max_length=2048, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I would try to keep the "reusability" to an absolute minimum. What I mean is don't try to reuse `Choice` or `Question` in multiple `Quiz`es, it doesn't matter if they contain the same information, let them be different. Hope this helps, let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers, so here's mine solution:

```
TYPES = (
    (1, 'One answer'),
    (2, 'Multiple answer'),
    (3, 'Text answer'),
)


class Quiz(CoreModel, models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Quiz'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Quizzes'
        ordering = ('id',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Question(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Question'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Questions'
        ordering = ('id',)

    title = models.CharField('Title (must be unique)', max_length=256, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField('Is active?', default=True, db_index=True)
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPES, default=1, verbose_name='Question type')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=2048, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='Question text')
    from_quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='Quiz', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Choice(CoreModel, models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Answer choice'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Answer choices'
        ordering = ('id',)
    from_question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Question')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=2048, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='Question text')
    correct = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Is it right choice?')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Answer(CoreModel, models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Answer'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Answers'
        ordering = ('id',)
    user_ip = models.CharField(max_length=2048, verbose_name='ip')
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='User', null=True)
    answered_question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Question')
    answer_choice = models.ForeignKey(Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Chosen option', null=True)
    answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=2048, null=True, verbose_name='Text answer')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Answer time')

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        if self.answer_choice is None and self.answer_text is None:
            raise ValidationError('Field 'answer_choice' and 'answer_text' are empty! '
                                  'Must be filled at least one of')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.answered_question} - {self.answer_choice or ""}{self.answer_text or ""}'
```

[image]

Answer model contain 2 fields of answers: FK to choice and text answer and clean method that check if at least one answer type field is filled.

Answer (score 0):

An answer should be able to have many choices, in your current architecture `Answer` has `choice` foreign key, i.e. it points to a single choice. Instead, I would create `choices` field on `Answers` that is of a text type and it should contain comma-separated IDs of choices.

You will need to perform a validation when creating an answer: if a question is a text type then there should be no choices, if single choice then it should be a single ID, if multiple then 1+ IDs.